# Calling a function on timer reaching zero a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a trivia game where a timer counts down as the user attempts to guess the correct answer. I have a function setup to start my `unanswered()` function below when the timer reaches zero. The unanswered function runs correctly the first time the timer reaches zero but the second time the timer reaches zero I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: unanswered is not a function at seconds.

```
function timerHolder() {
  clearInterval(clock);
  clock = setInterval(seconds, 1000);

  function seconds() {
    if (timer === 0) {
      clearInterval(clock);
      unanswered();
    } else if (timer > 0) {
      timer--;
      $('.time').html(timer);
    }
  }
}

function unanswered() {
unanswered++;
$('.time').html(timer);
$('.main').append("<p class='times-up'>Time's up!</p>");
$('.first-answer').css('background-color', 'green');
$('.times-up')
  .delay(2000)
  .fadeOut(400);
setTimeout(questionCounter, 2000);
```

Comment: `unanswered` is not defined in  your snippet. Where is it?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't think it was necessary since the problem sounded like it was with my timeholder function. I just added it.

Comment: Actually I found the problem and it was ironically with my unanswered function. I was increasing an unanswered variable that i needed to rename.